# Как установить кастомный UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Имеется `xib` файл с кастомной настройкой `UINavigationBar` (В xib файле все связал). Имеется `swift` файл с дополнительной конфигурацией бара. В `AppDelegate` делаю следующее:

```
let nc = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: GeneralNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
nc.setViewControllers([ProfileTableViewController()], animated: false)

let mainViewController = UITabBarController()
mainViewController.viewControllers = [nc]
window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
```

Запустив проект не получаю ожидаемого результата, вижу дефолтный белый бар навигации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К чему привязан настраиваемый `navBar`? Он должен быть сделан и привязан к каждому контроллеру. В каждом контроллере загружаешь `xib` и добавляешь его на `vc.view`.

Перед этим прячешь `navigationController.navigationBar` с помощью `.navigationBarHidden = YES;`